# Spring bean property set using xml configuration from other bean property

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-bean, spring-ioc

I have two bean classes like below

```
package com.abc;

public class Employee{

private String id;
private String name;
//setters & getters
}
```

and

```
package com.cda;

public class EmployeeDTO{

private String id;
private String name;
//setters & getters
}
```

I want to set the property fields from Employee to EmployeeDTO using spring xml configuration. Where data is coming from some other sources to the Employee Object.

Can you please help me on this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Use BeanUtils from apache or spring framework instead. Be careful about the argument positioning in these two ways. They are exactly opposite:

`org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object dest, Object orig)`

OR

`org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object source, Object target)`

Answer (score 0):

this is actually not a task that spring does for you. Spring is more about wiring all depending objects together that work together during runtime. What you need is a mapper like [mapstruct](http://mapstruct.org) or [enter link description here](http://dozer.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider a scenario
Where Employee gets it data from a datasource and now you want to map it to EmployeeDto
In such cases:

1. You can add a constructor in EmployeeDto which takes Employee as parameter and maps the field
2. You can use [ModelMapper](http://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application) where a simple line like:`EmployeeDto employeeDto = modelMapper.map(employee, EmployeeDto.class);` will work
3. Use [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) `import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;
   EmployeeDto newObject = new EmployeeDto();
   BeanUtils.copyProperties(newObject, oldObject);`  [reference](https://dzone.com/articles/how-copy-bean-properties)
4. Use [Jackson ObjectMapper](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) by the [convertValue()](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue(java.lang.Object,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference)) method: (not recommended due to performance issues)

`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Employee employee = ...;
EmployeeDto employeeDto = mapper.convertValue(employee, EmployeeDto.class);`